# How do I create a new column in pandas from the difference of two string columns?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

How can I create a new column in pandas that is the result of the difference of two other columns consisting of strings?

I have one column titled "Good_Address" which has entries like "123 Fake Street          Apt 101" and another column titled "Bad_Address" which has entries like "123 Fake Street". I want the output in column "Address_Difference" to be "          Apt101".

I've tried doing:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("AddressFile.csv")
data['Address Difference'] = data['GOOD_ADR1'].replace(data['BAD_ADR1'],'') 
data['Address Difference']
```

but this does not work. It seems that the result is just equal to "123 Fake Street          Apt101" (good address in the example above).

I've also tried:

```
data['Address Difference'] = data['GOOD_ADR1'].str.replace(data['BAD_ADR1'],'')
```

but this yields an error saying 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using `replace` with `regex`

```
data['Address Difference']=data['GOOD_ADR1'].replace(regex=r'(?i)'+ data['BAD_ADR1'],value="")
```

Comment: Seems to work pretty well in most cases. Let me append a question to this: if I see a good address like 123 N Main St Apt 101 and a bad address like 123 North Main St, why does this code return a value equal to the good address (i.e. 123 N Main St Apt 101)?

Comment: @L.Taylor since not match , it will return what you have in the good address column, pandas treat it as one string '123 N Main St Apt 101'

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a function that we can map across inputs.  This should be fast.

The function will use `str.find` to see if the other string is a subset.  If the result of `str.find` is `-1` then the substring could not be found.  Otherwise, extricate the substring given the position it was found and the length of the substring.

```
def rm(x, y):
  i = x.find(y)
  if i > -1:
    j = len(y)
    return x[:i] + x[i+j:]
  else:
    return x

df['Address Difference'] = [*map(rm, df.GOOD_ADR1, df.BAD_ADR1)]

df

          BAD_ADR1                GOOD_ADR1 Address Difference
0  123 Fake Street  123 Fake Street Apt 101            Apt 101
```

Comment: Very cool, I guess this would be very expensive computationaly speaking?

Comment: No.  You should try it.  In fact, I clock it at 1000 times faster on a dataframe of length 10,000

Comment: Will do! Thanks sir will add this to my code base for reference!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the bad address part from good address

```
df['Address_Difference'] = df['Good_Address'].replace(df['Bad_Address'], '', regex = True).str.strip()


    Bad_Address     Good_Address            Address_Difference
0   123 Fake Street 123 Fake Street Apt 101 Apt 101
```