# create a column which is the difference of two string columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'col1': ['apple;orange;pear', 'grape;apple;kiwi;pear'], 'col2': ['apple', 'grape;kiwi']})

    col1                    col2
0   apple;orange;pear       apple
1   grape;apple;kiwi;pear   grape;kiwi
```

I need the data like below:

```
    col1                     col2        col3
0   apple;orange;pear       apple       orange;pear
1   grape;apple;kiwi;pear   grape;kiwi  apple;pear
```

Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks.

In this example, the second row of col2 `grape;kiwi`, the sub-strings are in different position of the second row in col1 `grape;apple;kiwi;pear`. 
[[How do I create a new column in pandas from the difference of two string columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53288887/how-do-i-create-a-new-column-in-pandas-from-the-difference-of-two-string-columns][1])  does not work in my case.

Comment: What have *you* tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can use set to find the differences. As a first step, you need to convert the strings to a set.

```
df['col3'] = (
    df.apply(lambda x: ';'.join(set(x.col1.split(';')).difference(x.col2.split(';'))), 
             axis=1)
)

    col1                col2        col3
0   apple;orange;pear   apple       orange;pear
1   grape;apple;kiwi    grape;kiwi  apple;pear
```

Comment: works, but how do u account for the fact that set is unordered. so wen u merge back, it could be pear,orange instead of orange,pear. i guess the OP isnt concerned about that. just a tot. if u have a suggestion on that, it'd b great

Comment: If order matters, I would use a OrderedDict.

Answer (score 1):

Magic of `str.get_dummies`

```
s=df.col1.str.get_dummies(';').sub(df.col2.str.get_dummies(';'),fill_value=0)
df['col3']=s.eq(1).dot(s.columns+';').str[:-1]
df
                    col1        col2         col3
0      apple;orange;pear       apple  orange;pear
1  grape;apple;kiwi;pear  grape;kiwi   apple;pear
```

Comment: doesnt match with the expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy I use the df create by his code , not what his showed ,let me update

Comment: yeah, the code he posted is incorrect. noticed that as well

Comment: nice @YOBEN. clean, and keeps the order